# spring secruity 3.1: after login, not redirecting to welcome page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

following is my security configs:

```
    <security:http pattern="/login.*" security="none"/>
      <security:http realm="myrealm">
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_GROUPADMIN,ROLE_GROUP,ROLE_LOCMGR"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/*jsp" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_GROUPADMIN,ROLE_GROUP,ROLE_LOCMGR"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome.do" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_HD,ROLE_GROUPADMIN,ROLE_GROUP,ROLE_LOCMGR,ROLE_USER,ROLE_SCANNER"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/*do"   access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_GROUPADMIN,ROLE_GROUP,ROLE_LOCMGR,ROLE_USER"/>
            <security:form-login login-page="/login.do" 
                 default-target-url="/welcome.do" 
                 always-use-default-target="true"
                 authentication-failure-url="/login.do?login_error=1"/>
            <security:logout logout-success-url="/login.do" />
            <security:http-basic/>
            <security:anonymous />
     </security:http>

    <bean id="authProvider" class="AuthenticationProvider">
    </bean>     
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">  
        <security:authentication-provider ref="authProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

I can see the login page, after entering credentials and submit, it is not redirecting and refreshes the same login page.
in DEBUG mode I can see: `Authenticated SCOTT on local database`
I get the error message on wrong login-password..and reset password or forgot password link also works and redirects. But, not welconme page

it's failing at this point, when I debug, principal has authorities as role_admin and password has the right value. but, `newAuth` has null values after this `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` call!

```
Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, password);
```

EDIT: It was trying to goe througth the Authentication Manager because in my config, I am using 
`authentication-manager` and `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` method is expecting 3 parameters.

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(object principal, object credentials, collection authorities);
```

which will solve the issue!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` was trying to go througth the `Authentication Manager` because of the configs, `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` method is expecting 3 parameters.

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(object principal, object credentials, collection authorities);
```

by pasing the 3rd paramter `authorities` manager is satisfied `:)` and let the user to go through!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess what happens is that after the successfull login the browser actually gets redirected to `/welcome.do`, but the authenticated user is not authorized to see that page, so it gets sent back to the login page. Double-check (e.g. by enabling debug level logging) if the user really holds one of the authorities listed in:

```
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome.do" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_HD,ROLE_GROUPADMIN,ROLE_GROUP,ROLE_LOCMGR,ROLE_USER,ROLE_SCANNER"/>
```

Comment: user has role_admin...I can see that in my controller. But, when I debug, I got this: `/login.do has an empty filter list`..I will look into it..Thanks!

Comment: Of course `/login.do has an empty filter list`, because of the first line in your config. However this has nothing to do with your problem, I think.

Comment: this is where it is failing in my controller:`Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, password);` I have values for principal and password but, it retunrs nothing!

Comment: If the user is not authorized then 403 error is thrown it is not redirected to login page

Comment: Thanks guys...I need to pass authorities to this method inorder to go through..`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, password);` changed the above to `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, password, authorities);` and it worked!

Comment: You are not supposed to write such code. It's done in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` that intercepts POST requests sent to `/j_spring_security_check` (by default), and will authenticate the request using your configured `AuthenticationProvider`s.

Comment: @ArunPJohny is right, the default `AccessDeniedHandler` just responds with a 403, so it was a mistake on my side, sorry!

Comment: I think as long as it not custom security we are not supposed to use, but in custom-authenticationprovider or manager we can use this constrcutor! But, you might be right, might need to rethink about this!

Comment: That's correct, but you mentioned a controller not a custom auth provider. I should have said that you are not supposed to write such code in a controller.